# c# dialog opened from dialog closes the entire chain

Tags: c#, dialog, openfiledialog

oi. i have a generic form that creates its own controls dependent on the class passed it. in the interim before conversion to wpf, i have this problem:

this generic record edit form opens as dialog for a child record listed on a master record form. it opens as dialog because i want the user to focus only on that. if a child record attribute requires access to OpenFileDialog, closing OpenFileDialog closes the child record dialog as well.

any advice on how to stop this?

Comment: I think you'll need to post some code.

Comment: Where is the dialog being created? .ShowDialog() being called? is it from the parent or the child?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should help You - http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/769433-c-showdialog-inside-showdialog-closing-both-return

Comment: yes, that's what i was looking for, what happens when c# decides to pass down dialog response as a chain without my asking. i'll put in a similar work-around. thank you so much! (i also acknowledge your superior google-fu.)